# Is this JS bug?

Tags: javascript

I tried to run this code.

```
let a = b; //I'm sure that variable b is not defined.
```

> > Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined

I know this code causes this error.

```
b = 3;
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined

```
let b = 3
```

> Identifier 'b' has already been declared

Now, I can't put any String , Number,Null and Everything.
And I can't define variable 'b'.

Is this Js Bug?

Comment: It's because you're typing into the console, and the console environment is kind of weird when it comes to scoping. It also only occurs on some browsers. If you use `var` instead, it won't remain in the TDZ forever